# problems with nslookup commands

Tags: powershell, nslookup

I need to make a script to automate this manually entered process:

```
nslookup
> server ns1.server.com
> ls example.com
```

I need to save all the outputs of the ls in a txt or csv.

The fact is that I can not find any way to automate these 3 steps in one. And I've tried everything on powershell, bash ... and nothing. I have not been able to test in python or another language since the server does not have internet access to download corresponding libraries.

I would like to do something with this form nslookup ls example.com ns1.server.com> example.txt

But there is no way, help me pls.

Best Regards

Comment: So you can use send key or use sleep then send your second value in the interactive automation. But that is never a good way. What you can do is you can directly call `nslookup  ns1.server.com` which will help in direct result and redirect the output to a file either by input redirection(>>) or by piping it to `| Out-File`. But an oneliner solution would be to just a redirection `nslookup >> Filepath\filename.txt` and if you are seeing the console is being held use a trick as `nslookup exit >> filepath\filename.txt` .

Answer (score 0):

```
Resolve-DnsName example.com -Server ns1.server.com  -Type ALL | Out-File -FilePath example.txt
```

Comment: Thanks so much, but i need someone thing like this [link]( http://techgenix.com/nslookupanddnszonetransfers/)

Comment: Are you looking to automate an emulated zone transfer?

Answer (score 0):

You may find this useful:

```
PS C:\Temp>start-process nslookup -RedirectStandardoutput out.txt -RedirectStandardInput in.txt -RedirectStandardError  e.txt
```

with the following lines in `in.txt`

```
server example.com
ls -d example.com
exit
```